# Multiple editors in a Single Page

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor, tinymce

I want to achieve multiple editors on a single page. Like two editors in a single page. Do not want to use plugins; pure native coding.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor supports multiple inline as well as classic (contents in iframe) editors on a single page.

In both cases it is enough to specify path to `ckeditor.js` script on header page and CKEditor code will automatically:

- change all `div` elements with `contenteditable` attribute to inline editors
- "change" all `textarea` elements with class `ckeditor` to classic editors

Please also have a look at below samples and documentation links to get a better idea of how you can use multiple CKEditor instances on a single page:

- http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-11-11-07-04/full/samples/old/replacebyclass.html
- http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-11-11-07-04/full/samples/old/inlineall.html
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_framed
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_inline

**EDIT:**
Additionally you can use the [replaceAll](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll) method which replaces all `textarea` elements which match your criteria. This method requires writing JS on HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use a plugin.
TinyMce support multi-editor in one single page.
See documentation :
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/